# How to match whole words inside quotes with grep?

Tags: bash

I need to find string literals containing `ARM` or `arm` as a whole word in my C++ source code, for example they can be:

```
"ARM "
" ARM"
"abc ARM"
```

but the following should not match:

```
"Harmony"
"alarm "
```

I was able to do this

```
grep -riE -e '".*\sARM.*"' -e '".*ARM\s.*"' . --include={*.h,*.cpp}
```

but this marches `"alarm "`.

How to match only whole words?

Comment: Try the `-w` option of grep. But be careful: The idea what exactly is a whole word, can depend on your `LANG`. Think of cases like `"xbä.ö aüu` or `" しょうがない　です"`. Perhaps you should give a precise definition of what you consider a word; giving examples is not enough.

Comment: Is `"ARM-86"` a valid match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell grep to search for ARM that has nothing or a space plus whatever to the left and nothing or space plus whatever to the right.

```
grep -iEe '"(.* |)ARM( .*|)"'
```

Comment: where are the docs on how this `|` work?

Comment: I see a brief description in `man grep` under *Alternation*.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `grep` command:

```bash
grep -ir '"[^"]*\bARM\b[^"]*"' --include=*.cpp --include=*.h .
```

Here:

- `"[^"]*\bARM\b[^"]*"` will match full word `ARM` (due to word boundary) inside a pair of double quotes
- `--include=*.cpp --include=*.h` limits the search in `*.cpp` and `*.h` files only

Comment: what is `\b` for?

Comment: That is called word boundary as mentioned in my answer as well

Answer (score 1):

use the word boundary flag `\b` or `\< \>`:

```bash
# echo "arm abc" | egrep '".*\barm\b.*"|".*\<ARM\>.*"' <<EOF
> "abc ARM"
> " ARM"
> "ARM"
> "Harmmony"
> "alarm "
> EOF


"abc ARM"
" ARM"
"ARM"
```

This for for shell commands but should be similar in c/c++. just use consecutive backslahs, '\\b', in the source code.

Comment: need quotes `"abc ARM"`, for example

Comment: then just add the quotes. updated.